# where can I buy a new trim for my bath plughole?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom

My bath plughole needs replacing. I don't need the whole unit for the overflow. The problem is that when I fill the bath, half the water has drained away within 15mins. I think the plug doesn't fit properly. My husband thinks there's a leak around the trim. Both could be true. It's an old bath so probably has the old standard fittings (not metric). What's the least we need to replace? I've bought new plugs but they don't fit properly either. I'm looking for plug + plughole, but will I need to get an old style fitting?

Comment: It may be helpful to post a picture.

Answer (score 1):

Before you replace it, you may just need to take the fitting off and reseal it.

Every fitting is different, most hold the screen on with a screw and then the fitting itself unscrews from a thread adapter on the drain pipe. Once its off scrape off any old sealant. Make a 'snake' (like you did with clay as a kid) out of plumbers putty and lay that as a ring around the drain fitting. Screw your drain fitting back in and wipe up the excess putty.

How old is old? 10 years? 15? 20? 50? 100?

Pics would help.